# D3 way to change json data object properties?

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I'm using d3v4. Let's say I have the following data, `test.json`:

```json
{
    "nodes":[
      {"name":"a","width":60,"height":40},
      {"name":"b","width":60,"height":40},
      {"name":"c","width":60,"height":40},
      {"name":"d","width":60,"height":40},
      {"name":"e","width":60,"height":40},
      {"name":"f","width":60,"height":40},
      {"name":"g","width":60,"height":40}
    ],
}
```

I want to load this in an object using d3, and then change each "width" field there to original "width" value + 10 - and then use that changed object for D3 DOM calculations.

Here is an example code, which seems to work:

```js
var json_data = null;

d3.json("test_class_node.json", function (error, injsondata) {
  json_data = injsondata;
  // how best to do the below?
  for (var ix = 0; ix < json_data.nodes.length; ix++) {
    json_data.nodes[ix].width = json_data.nodes[ix].width + 10;
  }
}

var boxes = d3.selectAll('.box')
    .data(d3.keys(json_data))
    .enter()
    .append('div')
    .attr('width', function (d) { return d.width; })
    .attr('class','box');
```

My guess is, there must be a more readable D3 method, instead of doing a manual loop with `json_data.nodes[i].width = json_data.nodes[i].width + 10;` inside; ... is there such a method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like the following:

```
d3.json("test_class_node.json", function (error, injsondata) {
  json_data = injsondata;
  json_data.nodes.forEach(function (d) {
    d.width = d.width + 10;
  });
  console.log(json_data)
}
```

If at all possible, though, I'd recommend using the latest version of D3, which is now version 7. In more recent versions, `d3.json` returns a Promise. The code would then look like so:

```
d3.json("test_class_node.json").then(function (json_data) {
  json_data.nodes.forEach(function (d) {
    d.width = d.width + 10;
  });
  console.log(json_data);
})
```

In both cases, this is really a Javascript issue more than it's a D3 issue. Note that `json_data.nodes` is an array and we're iterating over the elements of the array using its `forEach` method.

Comment: Fantastic, the examples look great - thanks for an in-depth answer!